# Reverse for 'show_message' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['messages/<slug:the_sender>/$']

Tags: python, html, django, slug

I believe the issue lies with slugs. I am not sure what's happening though.

```
Urls.py:
    path('messages/', ShowMessageView.as_view(), name='message list'),
    path('messages/<slug:the_sender>/$', post_detail_view, name='show_message'),]

Views.py:     
class ShowMessageView(ListView):
    template_name="messages.html"
    model= SendMessageModel



class ShowDetailView(DetailView): 
    model= SendMessageModel
    slug_field = 'sender'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'the_sender'
    template_name="detailmessage.html"


post_detail_view = ShowDetailView.as_view()

messages.html: 

    {% for message in object_list %}
            {% if message.recipient == request.session.username %}
                <h5>{{message.datesent|date:'Y-m-d'}}<a href= "{% url 'show_messages'                                                                                                    message.the_sender %}">                            {{message.sender}}</h5>    
            {% endif %}
        
    {% endfor %}


Models.py
class SendMessageModel(models.Model): 
message= models.CharField(max_length=1000) 
sender= models.CharField(max_length=100)
recipient= models.CharField(max_length=100) 
datesent= models.DateField(max_length=100) 

def __str__(self):
    return self.sender
```

I am a beginner in Django so I am not really sure how most of the stuff works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why have you hard-coded your slug field? Could you please add your `sendMessageModel`?

Comment: @MeL I wanted the link to include the 'sender' field from my model. Added the model, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have slug fields in your model, only `CharField` and `DateField`. So if you want a `SlugField`, you need to define it as such:

```
slug = models.SlugField()
```

But maybe that is not really what you wanted to achieve? All you really need for you `DetailView` is:

```
class ShowDetailView(DetailView): 
    model= SendMessageModel
```

Now you already have access to the model fields in the template. What you did in `DetailView` was to set a new variable called "slug_url_kwarg" to a string, which will not get you anywhere.

So then you can change your template as follows:

```
{% url 'show_message' message.sender %}
```

Also change your `urls.py` as follows:

```
path('messages/<str:sender>/', post_detail_view, name='show_message'),
```